# Communicating with the UI in a bound service with RxJava

Tags: android

In my bound service, I use RxJava to process data. Subscribing to the observer takes place in the bound service. Since you can switch between IO threading and UI threading using schedulers, is it possible to communicate with the UI in the onSuccess method or does communicating with the UI still have to be done via the binder that the UI uses to access the service?